# How to put a text file on an tkinter entry

Tags: python, tkinter, textbox

I'm writing a code, that create a text file after pressing a button.
At the end of the code, after creating the txt, I'm trying to reopen the file and paste all the lines on a entry box or a label with multiples line, any help is good.

Thanks in advance

I know my code sucks because I'm really noob in python.
But this is my code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import os

HEIGHT = 500
WIDTH = 600

def get_anime_function (entry):
    if entry == "":
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "No hay link que buscar")
    else:
        url = entry
        txt = url.replace('https://animeflv.net/anime/', '')
        txt = txt + ".txt"
        r = requests.get(url)
        for line in r.text.splitlines():
            if 'var episodes =' in line:
                line = line.replace('    ', '')
                line = line.replace('var episodes = ', '')
                line = line.replace('[', '')
                line = line.replace(']', '')
                line = line.replace(';', '')
                break

        first_char = line[0:3]

        first_char = first_char.split(",",maxsplit=1)[0]

        first_char = int(first_char)

        url = url.replace('/anime/', '/ver/')

        for x in range(1, first_char+1):
            url2 =  url + "-" + str(x)
            r2 = requests.get(url2)
            html_content = r2.text
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'lxml')
            links = soup.find_all('a', href=True, attrs={'class':'Button Sm fa-download'})

            text = str(links)

            text = text.replace('[<a class="Button Sm fa-download" href="', '')
            text = text.replace('" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">DESCARGAR</a>]', '')
            text = text.replace('" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">DESCARGAR</a>, <a class="Button Sm fa-download" href="', '')
            text = text.replace('http://ouou.io/s/y0d65LCP?s=', '') #is ouo but the forum dont allow it
            text = text.replace('http', '\nhttp')

            text = os.linesep.join([s for s in text.splitlines() if s])

            text_file = open(txt, "a")

            for item in text.split():
                if "zippyshare" in item:
                    n = text_file.write(item + '\n')


            text_file.close()

    f = open(txt, "r")
    lower_entry['text'] = f
    f.close()

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

#background_image = tk.PhotoImage(file='background.png')
#background_label = tk.Label(root, image=background_image)
#background_label.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.place(relx = 0.5, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.1, anchor='n')

label = tk.Label(frame, text="Link de AnimeFLV", anchor='w')
label.place(relx = 0, rely=0, relwidth=0.65, relheight=0.4)

entry = tk.Entry(frame, font=40, justify='left')
entry.place(rely = 0.4, relwidth=0.65, relheight=0.5)

button = tk.Button(frame, text="Ejecutar", font=60, command=lambda: get_anime_function(entry.get()))
button.place(relx = 0.7, relwidth=0.3, relheight=1)

lower_frame = tk.Frame(root)
lower_frame.place(relx = 0.5, rely=0.25, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.6, anchor='n')

lower_entry = tk.Entry(lower_frame, font=60)
lower_entry.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: For multi-lines text, better use `Text` widget instead.  See [tkinter-text-widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm).

Comment: You can't really use an `Entry` widget - by design it only is for a single line of text. If you want to support more than one line you need to use a `Text` widget.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to programming and keep going! You will get better and don't be hard on yourself! Here is a sample to read a text file and display the contents on a label.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

with open("SomeTextFile.txt", "r") as f:
    Label(root, text=f.read()).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks for the help:
I'm get this output

<_io.TextIOWrapper name='otome-game-no-hametsu-flag-shika-nai-akuyaku-reijou-ni-tensei-shiteshimatta.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>

no the actual text that is inside

Comment: well at the end i use another code to open the text on a notepad, anyway i would use all the links that came out from there on a jdownloader :P

THANKS :)